# Is there a guide to Orkan language?

Tags: languages, mork-and-mindy

In the TV Series Mork and Mindy, we see a few words that are Orkan (see below).  Is there actually a guide/dictionary of Orkan language?

[(Mork and Mindy Wikia)](http://morkandmindy.wikia.com/wiki/Ork)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a more comprehensive dictionary available [here](http://archive.is/rqadV). It seems to reflect all of the words seen in the TV show.

I'm sure you'll wish to say aragato to me for finding this. No grebbles necessary.